# AJAX: Permission denied to access property in iframe

Tags: ajax

Hi I created an php website which uses  for AJAX post and was live at http://sprook.com.au/ but my client change it's domain to http://www.sprookit.net/ from his service provider Godaddy and now the firebug says:

> Permission denied to access property 'stopAjax'

here **stopAjax** is my method name.

script is there:

```
<div class="post_area">
            <form action="post.php" method="post" id="addVideo" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="post" onsubmit="return startAjax(this);">
                <iframe id="post" name="post" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
                <table width="860" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="435">POST YOUR AD FREE<br />
                            <em>Paste embed code from YouTube</em></td>
                        <td width="322"><input type="text" id="videoLink" name="videoLink" class="input_textbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="95"><input type="submit" name="set_video_link" id="set_video_link" value="" class="submt_post" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="process"> Connecting please wait <img src="images/loading.gif" /><br/>
                            </div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And all content comes from old domain i removed index file and it stoped working, therefore it is cleared that scripts run from old domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're running into [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue here as both script and iframe domain must match. You need to verify that all content really comes from new domain and not the old one.

Comment: Yes all content comes from old domain i removed index file and it stoped working, therefore it is cleared that scripts run from old domain

Comment: So, that's the problem then - the HTML comes from http://www.sprookit.net/ but AJAX call is being made from  http://sprook.com.au/.

Comment: No both AJAX call and HTML lies on .com.au but if I use .net Firebug throws error and if I use .com.au its fine.

Comment: _**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.sprookit.net/ from frame with URL http://www.sprook.com.au/post.php. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**_ - This is what shows up in Chrome, the issue is clearly due to same origin policy violation.

Comment: Just to make this absolutely clear: It doesn't matter where the script is loaded *from*. All that matters is the site *the script is running on* (think CDN)